how to add a vertex to a Bezier curvewith smooth control points
Given two end point (P0, P3), two control points(P1,P2) and a new vertex on the curve(v), I would like to calculate the two new control points for the new vertex that are aligned in smooth method meaning the two new control point and the new vertex are all linear.
Using the t location of the vertex, and the standard formulas:
new P1 Control Point = new PointF(t * p0.X + (1-t) * p1.X, t * p0.Y + (1-t) * p1.Y)
new P2 Control Point = new PointF(t * p2.X + (1-t) * p3.X, t * p2.Y + (1-t) * p3.Y)
SO far so good, but now Im looking for an equation (or code) that can give me the two new control points for the new vertex at t, but again, in smooth curve control.
I've tried using the derivatives of this equation have managed to get correct control point most of the time, however, the control points were not smooth and as this polygon can be across multiple quadrants, I have to make sure no mistakes there and also I have to make sure clockwise and counterclockwise(P0,P3 as well as P3,P0 order) do not effect the results
